# How to create a fallback class when Feign interface methods return HystrixCommands

Tags: java, asynchronous, spring-cloud-netflix, hystrix, feign

In order to create an asynchronous REST client with Spring Cloud, I am defining the following interface:

```
@FeignClient(name="RestClient", url="http://localhost:8081/v1", fallback=Fallback.class)
public interface RestClient {
  @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, path="/info/{id}")
  HystrixCommand<Model> getInfo(@PathVariable("id") String id);
}
```

I need to create the Fallback class, but in order to do that, my understanding is that the class must implement the RestClient interface.

The problem I run into is that the getInfo(...) method of my interface returns an HystrixCommand.  I tried to find examples or documentation for my use case, but everything I could find so far doesn't cover HystrixCommand as a return type.

Any idea how I should do this?

=== **Edit** ===

My current solution:

```
public class Fallback implements RestClient {

  public HystrixCommand<Domain> getInfo(String id) {
    return new ConstantHystrixCommand(new Model("data"));
  }

  private static class ConstantHystrixCommand<R> extends HystrixCommand<R> {
    private R fallbackData;

    public ConstantHystrixCommand(R fallbackData) {
      super(HystrixCommandGroupKey.Factory.asKey("uniqueName"));
      this.fallbackData = fallbackData;
    }

    protected R run() { return fallbackData; }
  }
}
```

The downside of this approach is that any instance of an "HystrixCommand" is registered in the Hystrix dashboard.  I would prefer not to have my fallbacks in there.  If you know of any other way to do it, please enlighten me.